# Opencv Feature Matching is not matching correctly for cropped images of different sizes and images taken from various sources?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, matching, opencv3.0, feature-descriptor

I am trying to match two images one is screen shot of mobile screen and template image is any app icon.If i match source and template cropped from same images it is matching perfectly.But when i use app icon cropped from different mobile screen it is not matching properly.

For image matching am working on the following code:

```
int main( int argc, char** argv )
{

Mat objectImg = imread("source.jpg", cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
Mat sceneImg = imread("note4-3.jpg", cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);

//cv::resize(sceneImg,sceneImg,objectImg.size(),0,0,CV_INTER_CUBIC);

if( !objectImg.data || !sceneImg.data )
{
    printf( " No image data \n " );
    return -1337;
}

std::vector<cv::KeyPoint> objectKeypoints;
std::vector<cv::KeyPoint> sceneKeypoints;
cv::Mat objectDescriptors;
cv::Mat sceneDescriptors;

Ptr<FeatureDetector> detector;
detector = cv::MSER::create();
detector->detect(objectImg, objectKeypoints);
detector->detect(sceneImg, sceneKeypoints);

Ptr<DescriptorExtractor> extractor = cv::ORB::create();
extractor->compute( objectImg, objectKeypoints, objectDescriptors );
extractor->compute( sceneImg, sceneKeypoints, sceneDescriptors );

if(objectDescriptors.type()!=CV_32F) {
objectDescriptors.convertTo(objectDescriptors, CV_32F);
}

if(sceneDescriptors.type()!=CV_32F) {
sceneDescriptors.convertTo(sceneDescriptors, CV_32F);
}

vector< vector<DMatch> > matches;
Ptr<DescriptorMatcher> matcher = DescriptorMatcher::create("BruteForce");
matcher->knnMatch( objectDescriptors, sceneDescriptors, matches, 8 );

double max_dist = 0; double min_dist = 100;

//-- Quick calculation of max and min distances between keypoints
for( int i = 0; i < objectDescriptors.rows; i++ )
{ 
    double dist = matches[i][0].distance;
    if( dist < min_dist ) min_dist = dist;
    if( dist > max_dist ) max_dist = dist;
}

std::vector<cv::DMatch> good_matches;

for( int i = 0; i < objectDescriptors.rows; i++ )
{ 
    if( matches[i][0].distance <= max(2*min_dist, 0.02) ) {
        good_matches.push_back( matches[i][0]); 
    }

}

//look whether the match is inside a defined area of the image
//only 25% of maximum of possible distance
/*double tresholdDist = 0.50 * sqrt(double(sceneImg.size().height*sceneImg.size().height + sceneImg.size().width*sceneImg.size().width));

vector< DMatch > good_matches2;
good_matches2.reserve(matches.size());  
for (size_t i = 0; i < matches.size(); ++i)
{ 
    for (int j = 0; j < matches[i].size(); j++)
    {
        Point2f from = objectKeypoints[matches[i][j].queryIdx].pt;
        Point2f to = sceneKeypoints[matches[i][j].trainIdx].pt;

        //calculate local distance for each possible match
        double dist = sqrt((from.x - to.x) * (from.x - to.x) + (from.y - to.y) * (from.y - to.y));

        //save as best match if local distance is in specified area and on same height
        if (dist < tresholdDist && abs(from.y-to.y)<5)
        {
            good_matches2.push_back(matches[i][j]);
            j = matches[i].size();
        }
    }
}*/

Mat allmatchs;
   drawMatches(objectImg,objectKeypoints,sceneImg,sceneKeypoints,good_matches,allmatchs,Scalar::all(-1), Scalar::all(-1),vector<char>(),0);
namedWindow("Matchs" , CV_WINDOW_NORMAL);
imshow( "Matchs",allmatchs);

waitKey(0);

}
```

[Wrong Match When cropped from different source][1]

The above result is obtained when matching source from one mobile screen shot and template from different screen shot.

I am using opencv3.0

Please help whether I have make changes in code or i have to use template matching or some other technique.I cannot use SUR detectors since i cannot have paid versions due to license conflits??

Sample images:

[Source Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3LM5P.jpg)

[Template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2gAf.png)

Comment: as you can see in your image, source and target don't hold the same keypoints. You'll have to find a feature detector that is more reliable for your type of images. In addition, maybe it isn't so smart to but all template icons in one big image, because if keypoints are detected in a big scale, the descriptor of a keypoint in one icon might include parts of neighboring icons, too. To analyze that you should draw the size/scale of the keypoints, too.

Comment: If your keypoints don't handle scale at all (I don't know MSER), the descriptors obviously don't work for different sizes of source and target.

Comment: can you please elaborate on the same and provide details where to modify the changes @Micka

Comment: just try a scale invariant feature detection/description combination as suggested by nbsrujan. Maybe try SURF in the beginning. I know that you can't use SURF for your product, but if it works better, you have a hint that it's more likely a problem of your detector-descriptor combination and not a problem of your images.

Comment: But STAR and BRIEF is not available in opencv3.0 how can i make use of it i tried all other combination and am supposed to use only opencv 3.0 @Micka

Comment: does it work with SURF? Did you try ORB for both, detection and description? ("Class implementing the ORB (oriented BRIEF) keypoint detector and descriptor extractor, described in [RRKB11]. The algorithm uses FAST in pyramids to detect stable keypoints, selects the strongest features using FAST or Harris response, finds their orientation using first-order moments and computes the descriptors using BRIEF (where the coordinates of random point pairs (or k-tuples) are rotated according to the measured orientation).")

Comment: I tried using ORB but compared to ORB MSER and ORB combination yields more accurate results but can i cange ORB and MSER initialisation parameters please am new to opencv please elaborate on the answer Thanks in advance @Micka

Comment: on such complex tasks as image retrieval you should try to understand what you are doing. One suggestions: If your icons don't change and you have perfect images (like screenshots instead of photographies) you can probably go better with template matching than with feature matching. Try cv::matchTemplate function and you should get quite good results (if you are able to exclude the background)

Comment: I did not used SURF because of license issue

Comment: No at first we used only template matching but it produces lot of false positive and its is not scale invariant so we are trying with feature based detection

Comment: @Micka can you please make modification to the above sample code for matching this kind f images

Comment: maybe if you provide sample images (which can be used as input), but I don't have much time.

Comment: i will provide sample images please try on this

Comment: I have provide source and template image can you please tyr on this

Comment: @Micka have you tested the code with other possible combinations??

Comment: no time sorry, only tested matchTemplate on multiple scales which gives promising results

Comment: if i scale template image can i get matches based on your suggestion and no problem thanks for your effort @Micka

Comment: @Micka Is GenericDescriptorMatcher removed in opencv3.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got better matches by the following combinations:
**Kaze detector
Kaze extractor
BruteForce-L1 matcher**
combined with cross check matching given in following link

http://ecee.colorado.edu/~siewerts/extra/ecen5043/ecen5043_code/sift/descriptor_extractor_matcher.cpp

Answer (score 1):

Looking at image you've provided, I can suggest some changes which will help you out.

- Remove selecting good matches, this creates issues when sharp features are present. Sharp features have very less hamming distance when compared to other good matches. When you select 2*min_dist , indirectly you are ignoring possible good matches.
- Make sure to have reasonable number of feature points in object image.
- If this feature detector and descriptor combination doesn't work out, select other feature detector and descriptors like STAR-BRIEF, SURF, which are far better then MSER-ORB.
- In your situation, detector-matcher need not be rotation invariant, it should be scale invariant. So try re-sizing object image

Hope my suggestions help you

Comment: Instead of good matches what is best way to filter good matches and i cannot use SURF can you please suggest some other combination and How can i make sure there are sufficient feature points in object image and STAR and BRIEF are not available in opencv 3.0

Comment: @Alagiri other detectors have options to select no. of features to be present in Image. So setting threshold would suffice.

Comment: can you please modify this code and post it or mail to me at alagiriforjob@gmail.com i have to submit the code can you please @nbsrujan